# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, scrolltop, onscroll

Sorry for my bad English but i've a question with a problem.

Here is the message I've :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Here is my function :

```
    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top<= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.heig
ht() > scrollPos) {
                $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't understand because I've an other page in local with this function and it's works fine.

I've search on the web but nothing correspond to my problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `$(currLink.attr("href"));` is not a valid selector. Could you post the HTML markup? Is the `href` value and `id` perhaps? (something like `#id`)

Comment: `refElement` appears to be `null`?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is the value of `currLink.attr("href")`. I suspect it's not what you think, so `refElement` isn't finding anything, and then `refElement.position()` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

change this line: `var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));`
in this line: `var refElement = $(currLink).attr("href");`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for the above issue. See the following code snippet

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
});

function onScroll(event){
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = currLink.attr("href");
        var splitEle = refElement.split('#');

        if ($("#"+splitEle[1]).offset().top <= scrollPos && $("#"+splitEle[1]).offset().top + $("#"+splitEle[1]).height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li').removeClass("active");
            currLink.parent().addClass("active");
        }else{
            currLink.parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```